# Visual Studio Code doesn't give java import suggestions with Language support for java plugin

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I've installed the Language support for Java ™ for Visual Studio Code plugin.
Set JDK_HOME and JRE_HOME environment variables and even edited the settings.json file from Visual Studio code to point java.home to the right place.

However Visual Studio code is still not suggesting imports.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

The plugin seems active as indicated by the thumbs up:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I can't give you an answer because I don't know what extension handles this but I didn't only install the language support but also an extension named "Java Extension Pack", maybe it will help resolve this issue. I think it something you should check-out and possibly install anyway since it contains a lot of useful stuff.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have that pack installed as well... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: This can now be done from within VS Code as of Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat Version 0.33.0. Open the command palette and type "java clean" (see official description in link).

Comment: well, this does nothing to restore intellisense and why would it.  The buggy-ass plug-in does not work

Comment: This works, but I have to run the command every time I restart VC code.

Answer (score 0):

vscode didn't show me the imports of `java.awt`

Follow the steps on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72851417/5517161

to have the import suggestions.