# VSCode won't import java.awt packages

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, importerror

I implemented ActionListener in my java class, but when I tried to auto-import (Shift+Alt+O), it gave this error:

> Running the contributed command: '_vscode_delegate_cmd_ksicrwzq' failed.

The whole code is here:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class myframe extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

myframe(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);

    JTextField text = new JTextField();
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,40));
}
```

Comment: Trying typing some of the code that you require, and press `Ctrl + Space` to generate the hints, if you select from one of those hints, it should auto import for you.

Answer (score 9):

I was having similar problem that is VS Code not showing imports for `java.awt` package as can be seen here. [image: here].

After a lot of research, I came to [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-gui#_develop-awt-applications)  explaining about Working with GUI in VS code.

### Solution

Follow the following steps:

#### Open Command Pallete:

You can open command pallete by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P` or `⌘ + Shift + P` for mac Users.

#### Go to `Java: Help Center`

[image: Command Pallete Search]

#### Go to `Students` tab:

Navigate to the Student's tab in Java: Help Center

#### `Enable AWT Development`

[image: Enabling AWT Development]

This procedure solved my issue and now VS Code is providing suggestions for `java.awt` package.

Answer (score 2):

See similar issue report in github: [Click the bulbs to Organize imports throws the error](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1840).

After `Cleaning Java Language Server Workspace` from **Command Palette**, hovering over the code then use `Quick Fix` to import needed jars instead of keyboard shortcuts. Then the error wouldn't happen again.

Answer (score -2):

Follow some steps for this

1. **CTRL + .**
2. Search (Filtered Types)
3. Click On Edit in **settings.json**
4. Replace **java.awt.*** with **java.awt.List**,

```
      "java.awt.List",
      "com.sun.*",
      "sun.*",
      "jdk.*",
      "org.graalvm.*",
      "io.micrometer.shaded.*"
```